# How to setup python environment in docker in my case?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to setup my python environment in docker.

My docker image is like this:

```
FROM python:2.7
# updating repository
RUN apt-get update

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8888

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

with this build command:

```
docker build -t ml-python-2.7 .
```

After image is built, 
I ran

```
docker run -it --rm --name ml-container  ml-python-2.7 python test.py
```

My sample `test.py`

```
print('test here')
```

It works when I first run this command.

```
docker run -it --rm --name ml-container  ml-python-2.7 python test.py
```

but after I change the `test.py` to `print('second test')`
and run the above command again, it still output test here.

How do I make sure it updates automatically or if there is more elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you simply modifying test.py in the current directory? The running docker container can't see inside your current directory.

Comment: either mount the current directory in docker ( use -v option), get in to bash inside docker and edit the file

Comment: @vumaasha Could you give me an example to set it up?

Comment: @Jwqq check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker does not store the changes you are making to files inside the container unless you commit it. If you want it to do so, you need to do a Docker Commit like:

`docker commit <CONTAINER NAME HERE>`

Or you could mount a local folder to the docker image like this:

```
docker run -ti -v ~/folder_in_host:/var/log/folder_in_container <IMAGE NAME HERE>
```